# Display data in Jade with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I've been trying to grab my data that's stored in mongodb and display it with a simple Jade template. I'm kinda new to this and I'm totally lost at this point.

Here's my output when I render my collection on /yfirlit

[image: MongoDB output on yfirlit-page]

The express router for /yfirlit looks like this

```
apiRouter.get('/yfirlit', function(req, res){
  apiUser.find(function(err, users) {
     if(err) res.send(err);
       res.render('yfirlit', {title: 'Yfirlit', users: users});
    });
});
```

My simple Jade Template

```
html
  head
   title!= title
  body
    div #{users}
    p
     | API
```

When I run the test the whole mongodb collection is displayed on the site. What I'm looking for is to be able to display only a portion of the documents in the collections. For example: I tried to display only the name property in the Jade template but was unable to get it right.

```
html
  head
   title!= title
  body
    div #{users.name}
    p
     | API
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm so lost and I would love to be able to render out only the properties that I wanted instead of the whole thing like in the picture.

Cheers!

Comment: My formatting for the code is kinda off. I'm trying to fix it but I having some problems with it. Apologies.

Comment: you need to use `res.render` to pass data to your view. http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html, also you might want to check if the data coming back is an array or is truly a single object.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I figured it out, I just needed to add the number of the object and then reference the property of the corresponding object. The res.send was a typo. The actual code had res.render.

Answer (score 1):

As Sgnl said, within the route you'll need to render the Jade view and include the data just like you have, but by using `res.render`:

```
apiRouter.get('/yfirlit', function(req, res){
  apiUser.find(function(err, users) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'yfirlit',
      users: users
    })
  });
});
```

...And I think you'll also need a loop to display the data from within your Jade view, because it contains multiple values:

```
if users
  each user in users
    div #{user.name}
```

Comment: the res.send was a typo. The actual code was res.render, sorry my mistake. You're right on needing to loop. Once i did div #{users[2].name} the correct name was displayed. Thanks for your help :)